# Why is it that a reviewer with full edit privileges cannot single-handedly approve an edit without improving it?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, suggested-edits

This issue seems to be a universal feature of SE. If a user suggests an edit, two users with access to the review queue are necessary to validate the edit, even if the first reviewer has full edit privileges. Why is that so? Reviewers with edit privileges can override the edit using "Improve Edit" or "Reject and Edit", do the same edit themselves, and get it applied immediately. However, if instead they just "approve" the edit, it is necessary to wait for another user approval.

Is there a reason to keep this feature?

Comment: "If a user suggests an edit, two users with access to the review queue are necessary to validate the edit, even if the first user has the "edit applied immediately" privilege" - By 'the first user' do you mean the first reviewer in this instance?

Comment: @Spevacus yes, the first person to review the edit could in principle do the edit themself if they have the privilege.

Comment: It's worth noting that when reviewing I can singlehandedly approve it by myself if I do `Approve and Edit` (assuming there is something else to be improved, that is)

Comment: @cocomac the actual option is "improve edit", but as you say there is a conditional there seems to require a reason to improve.

Comment: The TL;DR is... Quality. It's extremely easy to hit "Approve" on an edit that might not be that great of an edit. It's less likely that two people robotically click "Approve" on a bad edit. It's much less likely that someone hits one of the improvement options and actually makes changes themselves and *those* end up being bad changes.